# Missing OneNote commands

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-onenote

I can't find the "Convert Text to Table..." option in OneNote. I have it in Outlook/Word, but I can't find it at all in OneNote.

Below are screenshots of Word Options and OneNote Options respectively, for the Customize Ribbon tab. The scrollbar is much smaller in OneNote. There seem to be loads of commands that aren't available.

[image: Word Options] [image: OneNote Options]

I am using Office 2016.

How can I get the "Convert Text to Table..." command onto my OneNote ribbon?

Thanks.

Comment: You have to use a plugin. There are a few, but they all cost $$.

Comment: @DavidPostill thanks. That's a shame. I guess I'll continue with my current workflow of open word, paste, convert, copy.